NavController gets stuck after calling navigate()
This is my nav_graph.xml:
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/sale_fragment"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sale_fragment"
        android:name="cyberdynesoftware.mitiendita.SaleFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scanner" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/products_fragment"
        android:name="cyberdynesoftware.mitiendita.ProductsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_db_item" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categories_fragment"
        android:name="cyberdynesoftware.mitiendita.CategoriesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_db_item" />
</navigation>

In MainActivity.onCreate things are set up like this:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.mainView.toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val topDest = setOf(R.id.sale_fragment, R.id.products_fragment, R.id.categories_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(topDest, binding.drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

This is activity_main.xml:
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        layout="@layout/activity_main_view" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

and activity_main_view.xml:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

and finally there is the nav_menu.xml:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sale_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:title="@string/sale"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/products_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_format_list_bulleted_24"
        android:title="@string/products"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/categories_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_sort_24"
        android:title="@string/categories" />
</menu>

This is all working well so far. I have a drawer on the right and can navigate to all my fragments. However, when I navigate from SaleFragment to ProductFragment in code like this:
val navController = findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navController.navigate(R.id.products_fragment)

suddenly I can't navigate to SaleFragment anymore via the Sale item in the drawer. When I tap it the app stays at ProductFragment and the drawer doesn't even close. I can however navigate back to the SaleFragment with the device's back button.
Thus the back button somehow unstucks the navController. It seems to me that calling navigate(R.id.products_fragment) makes the navController believe that I navigated down in the hierarchie and thus need to navigate up again using the back button. But ProductsFragment is in fact a top level destination. Could this somehow derail the navController?
Anyway, how can I fix this?
